# How to send unauthenticated devise users to sign up page rather than login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

If a user is unauthenticated using the before filter in a controller like below ...

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

... Devise sends the user to the login (new_session) page by default.

How can I send them to the signup page (new_registration) instead?

Do I need to override some method in the application or devise controller?

Answer (score 0):

In Routes.rb

```
    devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
    root '(something)', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
    root 'new_user_registration#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
   end
 end
```

Comment: I tried this but doesnt seem to be working.   ` devise_scope :user do

    unauthenticated do
     root 'static_pages#home', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end

  end`

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Did you set up the authenticated route?

Comment: needed to be       root to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :unauthenticated_root

Answer (score 0):

Some of the code was working, but a logged out user could not access the homepage without being authenticated.  Not what I wanted.  This was the solution

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

and changed a piece of the code to..

```
def redirect_url
  new_user_registration_url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom failure app with a route method that returns a symbol representing the named route to redirect to:

```
# app/lib/my_failure_app.rb
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    :new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

Then inside the Devise initializer, specify your failure app:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = MyFailureApp
end
```

If you’re getting an uninitialized constant CustomFailure error, and you’ve put the CustomFailure class under your /lib directory, make sure to autoload your lib files in your application.rb file, like below

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated